# Angular router with data re-resolve after update

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router

I have a component where the data is resolved by the router, like:

```
this.route.data.subscribe((data => { .....
```

Now we've added an http post transaction to this component that changes the state of the data that we resolved.

Is there a handy way to re-resolve the route data?

Adding some more code... some things were changed to protected the IP, so forgive any syntax errors.

In a sub-component, subscribing to the post:

```
this.myDataService.postUpdate(id, this.noteText).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.userMessageService.send('success', 'Update Complete', 'The update has been updated.');
  },
  error => this.userMessageService.send('error', 'Update Error', 'The update failed: ' + <any>error)
);
```

Then in "myDataService":

```
postUpdate(id: number, notes: string) {
    return this.http
        .post(this.url,
        { "Id": id, "Notes": notes }, options)
        .map((res) => {
            return {};
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            return Observable.throw(e.message || e);
        });
}
```

Comment: can you post your http post code? where did you add the http post?

Comment: The http post is in a service and it is called from a sub-component of the main component. The sub-component subscribes to the post. I'll add some more code to the OP if you think it will help.

Comment: It sounds like you need something like ViewChild (http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/) within your this.route.data.subscribe() in the main component, you can trigger the sub-components method to subscribe to the post.

Comment: @LLai, I could add that. But let's pretend the call to the post service is in the main component. I would still have the same question. How can I re-resolve the data after the post completes?

Comment: hmm I guess I am confused by "re-resolve". Do you want to refire the first http request that is handled in the resolve? so resolve -> post -> resolve

Comment: @LLai, yes. I could do it by using: location.reload(), but that would do too much. My first thought had been to redirect back to that route, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149147/discussion-between-llai-and-mike-witt).

Comment: @LLai, I would move to chat but it is blocked by corporate IT.

Answer (score 0):

I would chain your observables together with flatMap.

```
// in your main.component
this.route.data.flatMap(res => { 
    return this.myDataService.postUpdate(id, this.noteText);
}) 
.flatMap(res => { 
    return this.myDataService.initialObservable(); // This is the same observable that you have in your resolve guard
} 
.subscribe(res => { 
    // called when 3 successive http request have finished 
});
```